# Pass a generic Object to a list in a method - JAVA

Tags: java, list, object

I've two question, They may be silly questions but it got me confused now.

**QUESTION 1:**

I've this code:

```
private List<Car> carList;

public void setData(List<Object> list)
{
    this.carListist = list;
}
```

But on `this.carList = list` I get a compiling error: `incompatible types, required: List<Car> but found List<Object>`

My question is, why this error?
Isn't List a list of objects type Car? So why doesn't it accept an Object there?

**QUESTION 2:**
I change the above code to the following and the error goes away:

```
private List<Object> carList;

public void setData(List<Object> list)
{
    this.carListist = list;
}


public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {

    Car car = carList.get(row); //Compiling error here

    switch(column)
    {
        (...)
    }
    (..)
```

Ther compiling error (signed in the code comment) is `incompatible types, required Car but found Object`
What I don't understand is, now list is defined as an object list. Car is an object. Why car, as being an object, is not accepted?

Anyway to fix this for both question 1 and 2?

Comment: What if that list has a `Monkey` in it?

Comment: To OP: In both 1 and 2 apply SLaks' comment. Note that there is no covariance, i.e `A extends B` does not imply `List<A> extends List<B>`.

Comment: `Car` is **always** an `Object`.  `Object` could **potentially** be a `Car`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not because every Car is an Object that a list of cars is also a list of objects, in your example what if the list of objects contains a boat and not a car....

Comment: Or a socket, for that matter...